# why append() used on <select> element only append string? while using jquery append() can append an <option>

Tags: jquery, select, append

I'm not sure why I have to use jquery.append() to add an  to an  element.

I thought there is an  Element.append()for js.

```
 var currentOption =`<option id="startTimeDisplay" style="outline-color:light-blue" disabled selected value="${timeValue}">${timeValue}</option>`
```

```
const elemStartTime = document.querySelector("#startTimeSelector");
elemStartTime.append(currentOption)
console.log(elemStartTime)
```

```
<select  id='startDateSelect' class="browser-default right-align color-#e8eaf6 indigo lighten-4 ">
     "<option id="startDateDisplay" value="" disabled selected></option>"
  </select>
```

This does not even show up on the html

vs
Using jquery it works fine.

```
$('#startTimeSelector').append(currentOption);
```

```
<select  id='startDateSelect' class="browser-default right-align color-#e8eaf6 indigo lighten-4 ">
     <option id="startDateDisplay" value="" disabled selected></option>
  </select>
```

Comment: jQuery append is not the same as DOM append. jQuery parses HTML, DOM doesn't.

Comment: For DOM use `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Comment: Hello @Thomasjd, can you be more specific about what are you asking? This site is question+aswer based, not opinion based.

Comment: I was mixing up append() and appendTo().  Sorry that was just a silly mistake.

Comment: `"#startTimeSelector"` doesn't exist in the HTML you've posted.